# Can we make Single JDBC Sink Connector for multiple source db if primary key is same in all source DB?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mssql-jdbc

Below is my JDBC Sink Connector Configuration Properties.

```
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement": "$1",
    "table.name.format": "kafka_${topic}",
    "connection.password": "********",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "topics": "aiq.db1.Test1,aiq.db1.Test2,aiq.db2.Topic1,aiq.db2.Topic2",
    "batch.size": "3000",
    "transforms": "dropPrefix",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex": "aiq.(.*)",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "connection.user": "admin",
    "name": "MSSQL_jdbc_sink_connect",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "pk.mode": "record_value",
    "pk.fields": "id"
```

If I used this then connector is looking for db1 or db2, which is source db and giving this error.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Database 'db2' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessagesException(JdbcSinkTask.java:150)
at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:102)
... 11 more
[2022-01-25 06:09:09,582] WARN Write of 500 records failed, remainingRetries=10 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:92)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Database 'db2' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

Please let me know Can I create a JDBC sink connector which uses more than one databases for source topic.
If this scenario is possible then How can I achieve this by using JDBC Sink Connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used these properties and it worked for me in this case(if we have multiple source db and one target db to store that data)

```
table.name.format=iq_${topic}
transforms=dropPrefix
transforms.dropPrefix.replacement=$1_transferiq_$2
transforms.dropPrefix.regex=iq.(.*).transferiq.(.*)
transforms.dropPrefix.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `connection.url` can only refer to one database at a time, for an authenticated user to that database.

If you need to write different topics to different databases, copy your connector config, and change the appropriate configs

Comment: I'm not using different target database to write data of different topics, I'm using the same database to write data of multiple topics in different target database tables. I am asking If I have multiple topics and those topics data coming from different source databases and I want to store that data in a same target db, If the primary key is same in all source databases.

Comment: You're using the same **server**. But different **database schemas**. As the error says - `Database 'db2' does not exist`. No part of your config, other than the topic name has "db2" in it. So, regardless of keys, you should try to create a duplicate connector config for `aiq.db2.Topic1,aiq.db2.Topic2` and run `CREATE DATABASE db2` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=sqlpool

Comment: This is useful, if we have to write different topics to different databases.